# How to add ellipses to each cluster of 3D scatter plot using updatemenus in plotly R?

Tags: r, plotly, ellipse

I wanted to create 3D scatter plot in R plotly and add ellipses to each cluster of plot using updatemenue. (Something similar to "Relayout Button" section in  https://plot.ly/r/custom-buttons/#relayout-button but for 3D one). I'm able to add ellipses using ellipse3d to plotly plot but I don't know how to make it interactive with updatemenue layout. 
I wrote below code but not adding updatemenus yet. Would you please give me a help?

```
df<-
structure(list(C = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("h", "j", "k", "l"), class = "factor"), 
R = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 
2L, 3L), .Label = c("a", "b", "c"), class = "factor"), 
p1 = c(-58.2553800845032, -56.8446241583638, -57.4730903743034, 
9.69295162882175, 23.2783600609086, 17.5961245834489, 27.1776771896781, 
31.8555589999195, 31.1329423894753, 5.49176565720366, 12.9720812431292, 
13.3756328645854), p2 = c(1.89343789795219, 2.96630118684064, 
3.36783254906029, 22.1036613994383, 19.1821210966211, 26.161634708624, 
0.00600630960161123, 6.18082767371698, 1.73282189156538, 
-26.351364716711, -26.6021818789505, -30.641098117759), p3 = c(1.98930539820297, 
3.3628193816464, 4.50430994627108, -16.0161352497141, -10.0505758631406, 
-3.19889710494869, 8.92935203885341, 7.00720243933593, 22.7494673296249, 
-11.7929746942337, -5.26783717642642, -2.21603644547113)), .Names = c("C", 
"R", "p1", "p2", "p3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))

library(plotly)
library(corpcor)
library(rgl)
x=df$p1; y=df$p2;  z=df$p3
col <- c("orange", "blue", "purple", "green")
p <- plot_ly(df, x =x, y = y, z = z,type = "scatter3d",
         mode = "markers", marker = list(color = col[df$C],
         showscale = FALSE)
       #, text = paste(df$C, df$R)
      )
groups <- df$C
levs <- levels(groups)
group.col <- c("red", "blue", "yellow", "green") 
for (i in 1:length(levs)) {
group <- levs[i]
selected <- groups == group
xx <- x[selected]; yy <- y[selected]; zz <- z[selected]
co<- cov(cbind(xx,yy,zz))
S<- make.positive.definite(co)
ellips <- ellipse3d(S, centre=c(mean(xx),mean(yy),mean(zz)), level = 0.95)
p<- add_trace(p, x = ellips$vb[1,], y = ellips$vb[2,], z = ellips$vb[3,]
           ,type = 'scatter3d', size = 1      
            ,opacity=0.002
            #,color= group.col[i]
            ,showlegend = FALSE)
 }
print(p)
```

Comment: use `dput()` to add your dataset to your post.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my post.

Comment: You should review your code. It does not work and there are some errors in it. For instance in `p <- plot_ly(df, x =x, y = y, z = z` you are using df (there is no x, y, z in df ) but also `x`, `y`, and `z` you defined in the line before.

Comment: @MLavoie Now it works.

Comment: nope, stil an error: Error in make.positive.definite(co) : 
  could not find function "make.positive.definite"

Comment: library(corpcor), Added to post.

Comment: the libraries used to run your code should be posted in your post as well!

Comment: I added all required packages.